# String array storing time

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a simple method that creates numbers 13:35 - 14:31.  Right now all it does is print out the numbers using a

> Console.WriteLine

I was wondering if there's a way to store this into an array say

> string[] numbers = new string[57];

Here is what I have so far:

```
 int min1 = 1;
        int min2 = 3;
        int sec1 = 3;
        int sec2 = 5;
        string a = "{0}{1}:{2}{3}";
        string[] numbers = new string[57];
        for (int i = 0; i < 57; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a,min1, min2, sec1, sec2);

            sec2 = sec2 + 1;
            if (sec2 == 10)
            {
                sec2 = 0;
                sec1 = sec1 + 1;
            }
            if (sec1 == 6 && sec2 == 0)
            {
                sec1 = 0;
                sec2 = 0;
                min2 = min2 + 1;
            }
            if (min2 == 0)
            {
                min2 = 0;
                min1 = min1 + 1;
            }

        }
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `string.Format` for that:

```
numbers[i] = string.Format(a, min1, min2, sec1, sec2);
```

Comment: Thank you dasbinkenlight you're the best!

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for:

```
numbers[i] = string.Format(a,min1, min2, sec1, sec2);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        numbers[i] = String.Format(a,min1, min2, sec1, sec2);
```